# Не работает команда npm start, в чем причина?

Tags: npm

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не работает команда npm start, в чем причина?

Comment: Не используйте кириллицу.

Comment: Так английским по чёрному написано, что у вас нет скрипта start